# JackRabbit - Access media content through android

Tags: android, mobile, streaming, jackrabbit, multimedia

**Brief**: I have a portal that uploads content to Apache JackRabbit (content mainly contains audio & video files).

There is a mobile client application (Android) that needs to access these audio / video files from the repository. I have exposed a REST service that returns to the mobile application all the relevant unique identifiers (identifier / uuid returned by jackrabbit after adding).

**Question**: Now to stream the audio / video, what shall be the best way of communication between the mobile app and the server?

Is it possible to have a servlet that takes the uuid, gets the node (or the payload) and throws it on to the stream?

Is there any other mechanism that can be used?

Please suggest!!

Comment: I would use HTTP. And I would not use UUIDs, but paths.

Comment: Agree, Paths is a better option than UUID and I have been working on that part. The REST service will return the paths to the mobile application. Regarding your comment "I would use HTTP", could you please ellaborate more on it? Is it like using a Servlet which I mentioned above?

Comment: I wrote "I would use HTTP" because your question is not clear enough ("what shall be the best way of communication" is very vague).